# How can I add an extra flag to Leksah?

Tags: ide, haskell

How can I add an extra flag to Leksah?

I'm getting this error:

> You need -XDeriveDataTypeable to derive an instance ....

Where can I add the extra flag in Leksah?

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to `Package -> Edit`
2. Select the tab `1 Extensions`
3. Check the box for the language extension(s) you need
   (`EnableExtension DeriveDataTypable`)
4. Click `Save` in the lower right hand corner

Now the package will be compiler with the desired language extension(s)!